# yii extension : how to show the user's role at user grid view?

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

Q : How to show the user's role at user grid view?

Description : I'm using user and rights extension. I would like to show the user's role at grid view of user/admin. and filter by user's role. How can I?

this is my view

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'user-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'name' => 'username',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::link(UHtml::markSearch($data,"username"),array("admin/view","id"=>$data->id))',
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'email',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>'CHtml::link(UHtml::markSearch($data,"email"), "mailto:".$data->email)',
        ),
        'create_at',
        'lastvisit_at',
        array(
            'name'=>'status',
            'value'=>'User::itemAlias("UserStatus",$data->status)',
            'filter' => User::itemAlias("UserStatus"),
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

This is my controller

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $rasdataProvider = new RAssignmentDataProvider();
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('User', array(
            'criteria'=>array(
                'condition'=>'status>'.User::STATUS_BANNED,
            ),

            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>Yii::app()->controller->module->user_page_size,
            ),
        ));

        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            'rasdataProvider'=>$rasdataProvider,
        ));
    }
```

update #1

this is the relation of user.php

```
    public function relations()
    {
        $relations = Yii::app()->getModule('user')->relations;
        if (!isset($relations['profile']))
            $relations['profile'] = array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Profile', 'user_id');
        return $relations;
    }
```

Comment: Please, give us link for user and rights extension.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rights/  http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user/

Answer (score 2):

Try add profile.role

```
'columns'=>array(
    array(
        'name' => 'username',
        'type'=>'raw',
        'value' => 'CHtml::link(UHtml::markSearch($data,"username"),array("admin/view","id"=>$data->id))',
    ),
    'profile.role', // through relation `profile`
```

Comment: showing the error "Property "Profile.role" is not defined." I update my question. How can I add a relation?

Comment: do u use User model? Check it out $relations['profile'] = array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Profile', 'user_id'); in mishamx-yii-user-fc69518/models/User.php

Comment: it is already included in the model/user.php of user extension.

Comment: Because profile is defined, I think in relation `profile` is wrong. Check otu field `role` in Profile

Comment: do you mean at DB? There isn't any role field at profiles tbl

Comment: I changed //'users'=>$this->_authorizer->getSuperusers() to
    'roles'=>array('Rights::module()->superuserName') at assignmen, authitem controller, only. rest of them I didn't change any thing

Comment: Sergey, any idea? pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

Below example should do the trick. Copy this into your columns array.

```
array(
    'name'=>'assignments',
    'header'=>Rights::t('core', 'Roles'),
    'type'=>'raw',
    'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'role-column'),
    'value'=>'$data->getAssignmentsText(CAuthItem::TYPE_ROLE)',
),
```

This is taken from rights/view/assignment/view.php file.